# Zend Framework 1 cannot use where() method when using union()

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
$select = $logAdapter->select(); // an instance of Zend_Db_Select class
$select->union(array(
         "SELECT Country,Name
          FROM ManualLog_TheNew",
         "SELECT Country,Name
          FROM ManualLog_TheOld"),Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL);
$select->order("$param->orderBy")
         ->limit($param->length,$param->offset);
```

This work, but when I insert `where()` method before `$select->order()`, will throw error.

```
$select->where('ManualLog_TheOld.OperateTime >= ?' => "2014-06-30");
```

Error is:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Select_Exception' with message 'Invalid use of where clause with UNION' in /xxx/code/ZendFramework/Zend/Db/Select.php:880
```

I've been frustrated for about two days, please help me. Thank you.

@Claudio Venturini

I tried your answer, still have two questions:

1 The sql printed out are:

```
Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /code/ZendFramework/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 739
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /code/ZendFramework/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 740
Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /code/ZendFramework/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 739
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /code/ZendFramework/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 740
SELECT `ManualLog_TheOld`.`Country` 
FROM `` AS `ManualLog_TheOld` 
WHERE (OperateTime >= '2014-06-30') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT `ManualLog_TheNew`.`Country` 
FROM `` AS `ManualLog_TheNew` 
WHERE (OperateTime >= '2014-06-30') 
ORDER BY `OperateTime` desc LIMIT 200
```

How to remove the ``` from ``...as ```?

2 When I remove the ``` from `` ... as ``` and execute the sql, I got error below:

```
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'ManualLog_TheNew.OperateTime' in 'order clause'
```

But I have `OperateTime` field! What's wrong?

PS: I've got it, I should query the `OperateTime` field out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a `WHERE` condition on the outer `UNION` query. You can only use `WHERE` inside any of the subqueries in the `UNION`.

For example this is valid SQL

```
(SELECT Country,Name
    FROM ManualLog_TheNew
    WHERE condition1)
UNION
(SELECT Country,Name
    FROM ManualLog_TheOld
    WHERE condition2)
```

while the following is not valid:

```
(SELECT Country,Name FROM ManualLog_TheNew)
UNION
(SELECT Country,Name FROM ManualLog_TheOld)
WHERE condition
```

See the documentation on `UNION` for reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html

So to add the same `WHERE` condition programmatically in each condition you have to create each `SELECT` statement separately. Try the following:

```
$condition = 'OperateTime >= ?';
$conditionValue = '2014-06-30';

$selectOld = $logAdapter->select();
$selectOld->from(array('ManualLog_TheOld'), array('Country', 'Name'))
$selectOld->where($condition, $conditionValue);

$selectNew = $logAdapter->select();
$selectNew->from(array('ManualLog_TheNew'), array('Country', 'Name'))
$selectNew->where($condition, $conditionValue);

$select = $logAdapter->select();
$select->union(array($selectOld, $selectNew), Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL);

$select->order($param->orderBy)->limit($param->length, $param->offset);
```

Comment: Thanks, but my two `where` are the same, how could I modify my code to use two `where` separately using zf1?

Comment: So great of you! I'll have your code try later, thank you so much!!

Comment: I got it, I should query the field out too.